# cannot convert value of type [Any Object] to expect argumet type 'HourlyTemperatures'

Tags: swift

```
class func getHourlyWeather(searchString:String,completionHandler:(HourlyTemperatures)-> ()){


        var hourTemperatureArray = [AnyObject]()


         let hourtempObj = HourlyTemperatures(hourlyTemperatureInF:34 , hourlyTime: 2, hourlyIcon: sunny, hourlyAmPm: 4) as AnyObject

         hourTemperatureArray.append(hourtempObj)

                    }
                    completionHandler(hourTemperatureArray)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("error processing json data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }

            }
            else{
                print("Error details:: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }

        })
        task.resume()

    }


//function call

WeatherConnection.getHourlyWeather("AKhil",completionHandler: { (tempArray:HourlyTemperatures) -> () in
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the array of `[HourlyTemperatures]` then your `completionHandler` type should be `[HourlyTemperatures]` not `HourlyTemperatures`, also in your method you need to also call the `completionHandler` in the else part with empty `Array`. It is batter if you create array of `[HourlyTemperatures]` instead of `[AnyObject]`. So change your code like below.

```
class func getHourlyWeather(searchString:String,completionHandler:([HourlyTemperatures])-> ()){


    var hourTemperatureArray = [HourlyTemperatures]()


     let hourtempObj = HourlyTemperatures(hourlyTemperatureInF:34 , hourlyTime: 2, hourlyIcon: sunny, hourlyAmPm: 4) as AnyObject

     hourTemperatureArray.append(hourtempObj)




            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("error processing json data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            completionHandler(hourTemperatureArray)
        }
        else{
            completionHandler(hourTemperatureArray)
            print("Error details:: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }

    })
    task.resume()

}
```